Azure Blob Storage, retrieve paginated files with Java SDK and continuationToken give empty results
I want to access my Blob Storage and retrieve N file at time from my Java application.
While I can access the files, if I try to use the API iterableByPage I can not get any result.
I'm using the following dep:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.7.0</version>
</dependency>

And running this code:
String continuationToken = null;

BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerNameToSearchIn);

PagedIterable<BlobItem> blobHierarchyIterable = blobContainerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy(prefix); // No problem here: I can see all my files

Iterable<PagedResponse<BlobItem>> blobHierarchyPagedIterable = blobHierarchyIterable.iterableByPage(continuationToken, 10);

While inspecting the source code, I found that:
public Iterable<P> iterableByPage(C continuationToken, int preferredPageSize) {
    return this.pagedFlux.byPage(continuationToken, preferredPageSize).toIterable(this.batchSize);}

and
    @Override
    public Flux<P> byPage(C continuationToken, int preferredPageSize) {
        if (preferredPageSize <= 0) {
            return Flux.error(new IllegalArgumentException("preferredPageSize > 0 required but provided: "
                + preferredPageSize));
        }
        if (continuationToken == null) {
            return Flux.empty();
        }
        return byPage(this.pageRetrieverProvider, continuationToken, preferredPageSize);
    }

This confuse me: how I'm supposed to starting retrieving data without an initial continuation token? Because without one, I got an empty result that I can not use to retrieve the next token.
All advice welcome.
Thanks.
EDIT:
I don't know why my question was considered not OK.
I've checked the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-storage-blob-blobcontainerclient-listblobsbyhierarchy(java-lang-string)) and similar question here on Stack but every answer suggest me to do exactly what I'm already doing.


I want to access my Blob Storage and retrieve N files at a time from my Java application.

You can use the code below to retrieve the N number of files from Azure Blob Storage using Azure Java code.
Code:
import com.azure.core.http.rest.PagedIterable;
import com.azure.core.http.rest.PagedResponse;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobItem;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String folderName = "test";
        String continuationToken = null;
        int pageSize = 10; // Set your preferred page size here

        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
            .connectionString("<connection-string>")
            .containerName("<container-name>")
            .buildClient();
        
        PagedIterable<BlobItem> blobIterable = blobContainerClient.listBlobs();

        Iterable<PagedResponse<BlobItem>> blobPagedIterable = blobIterable.iterableByPage(continuationToken, pageSize);

        for (PagedResponse<BlobItem> response : blobPagedIterable) {
            System.out.println("Page:");
            for (BlobItem blobItem : response.getValue()) {
                if (blobItem.getName().startsWith(folderName)) {
                    System.out.println(blobItem.getName());
                }
            }
            continuationToken = response.getContinuationToken();
        }
    }
}

The above code retrieves a list of blobs in the container using the listBlobs method. It then uses the iterableByPage method to retrieve the blobs in pages, with a page size of 10. The code then loops through each page of results and prints the name of each blob that starts with the specified folder name.
Output:
Page:
test/0xx024 (1).html
test/03xxx024.html
test/04xxx24.html
test/0xx4 (1).html
test/05xxx.html
Page:
test/14-xxx4.html
test/15xxx4 (1).html
test/15xx.html
test/Aprxx2024 (1).html
test/Aprixxx-2024.html
test/Aprix-0xx4 (1).html
test/Marx-x-2024 (1).html
test/ffmpxx6.1.1.zip
test/saxlxe (1).png
test/saxmpxle.png
Page:
test/tx2 (1).jpg



Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I still have the same problem, despite coping your code line by line.
Here what happen while inspecting my code step by step during debugging:
Initial state: https://imgur.com/TPB1Txh
blobIterable state: https://imgur.com/jBjM3qi
blobPagedIterable state: https://imgur.com/104j04u
Can I ask what version of azure-storage-blob are you using, or any other important information about dependencies?

I'm using </dependency>     <dependency>     <groupId>com.azure</groupId>     <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>     <version>12.25.2</version> </dependency>

Worked after upgrading to the version suggested by you. Thanks again.
Marking as solved because it's a viable example and there is the indication for the problem around versions.
